# Make new character at Powershell (windows)

Tags: c, powershell

I develop C with powershell and I need some special characters.
Can you change the look of the characters? (I think, like on C64 for example when you draw a character as a human)

Comment: use a different font??

Comment: You cannot compare your PC with a C64. Each character shown in Powershell is defined in the font you use. Look up Microsoft's documentation how to change the font of the console in use. Then find the font that includes the visual representation you want, the term is "glyph" AFAIK. You can then output the code of that glyph.